# How to display recently viewed products in Porto Theme?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

i want to display recently viewed products in porto theme
i have created one widget for recently viewed products but it is not reflecting in home page.

Comment: better if you can include the code in your post

Comment: i didn't write any code i created only widget

Comment: well, can you include the widget code (generated)

Comment: where can i find that code ?

Answer (score 0):

For Porto theme you have to add this widget tags inside your Selected home cms page which is selected to use as a home page.
please follow this [link](https://meetanshi.com/blog/show-recently-viewed-products-in-magento-2/)

Let me know if still have any question.

Comment: i am new to magento could you please suggent me how to put widget tags?

Comment: just follow the link, here we can give you direction only If you are developer you can get it no issue in it.